# SlickGrid: large number gets converted to Exponential form

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am using [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid), here is the sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahdLeaoo/) of the issue which I am facing.

The values of last column (`effortDriven`) of the grid gets converted in scientific notation since it's `a large number`.

I am generating data using the loop:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
      data[i] = {
        title: "Task " + i,
        duration: "5 days",
        percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        start: "01/01/2009",
        finish: "01/05/2009",
        effortDriven:  i *  23000000000000000000000 // this value is shown in scientific notation
      };
    }
```

How can I avoid conversion of large number to `scientific notation`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(i *  23000000000000000000000).toLocaleString()`

Comment: thnx. It works as a string, bt i get the large data from server which is in form of number, I don't want to iterate over it to change number to string.

Comment: You can use formatter
{ id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven", formatter: function(row, cell, value) { return value.toLocaleString(); } }